# I want to store characters in an array of byte and write this byte array to a file and read the file back and output to the screen

Tags: java

I want to store characters in an array of byte and write this byte array to a file and read the file back and output to the screen.

Here is my code ( I'm just starting), can anyone help me?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   {
      File f=new File("input.txt");     
      FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);   
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);  
      int c = 0;             
      while((c = br.read()) != -1)         
      {
            char character = (char) c;          
            System.out.println(character);
```

Comment: Please explain what specific issue you're facing. Don't just ask someone to do it all, your question will be closed

Comment: I just need opinion or what should I do next.. "I want to store characters in an array of byte and write this byte array to a file and read the file back and output to the screen "

Comment: the problem is, when I run the program it stops

Comment: I mean, it does not read the character , then hangs

Comment: Hi Hannah, your code looks incomplete, can you edit your question to show all of your code, and explain exactly where it hangs. Has it read any characters when it hangs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see here Where do you write the character array to the file input.txt?
First you have to save the data to a file and then just read it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [] arr = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        byte[] bytes = String.valueOf(arr).getBytes();
        try(BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("input.txt"))) {
            bout.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       //then part of your code
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. It's better to ask for clarifications in comments before answering.

Comment: Dear after all, the author of the question explains that he is a beginner and looking at the pond it is clearly visible that he does not write characters to the file there

Comment: I thought that he should be given some direction of which queue this operation is taking place